# Re-render template when changing route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an application with two outlets (in the application.hbs), where-as the second renders a grid of videos that is displayed no matter on which route you are on, but the videos that are displayed can change. The important bits of the model"

```
App.Video = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    frontpage: DS.attr('boolean'),
    ...
});
```

So when I am on most routes I want to display the videos with frontpage == true and on one route I want to display all the videos, no matter what frontpage says.
I seem to have gotten it half working.
The important routes look like this:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('videos', { path: 'videos/' }, function () {
        this.route('video', { path: ':video_id' });
    });
    ...
```

And my `videos.index` template (which I render in the second, named outlet) looks like this:

```
{{#each video in controller}}
  {{log isFrontPage}}
  <!--if we only want to display the frontpage-videos in the grid -->
  {{#if isFrontPage}}
  <!--show only videos with frontpage = true -->
    {{#if video.frontpage}}
      {{partial 'video-thumbnails'}}
    {{/if}}
  {{else}}
    <!--show all videos, which will be used for the /videos site-->
    {{partial 'video-thumbnails'}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

The isFrontPage is a property in the ApplicationController, that gets set to true/false in the right routes. When I initially load the index route it all works fine and just loads the videos with `frontpage==true`, when I then switch to the `/videos` route it all works fine as well and it loads all the videos. But then, no matter what route I go on, it just stays the same. And interestingly enough, even though the displayed videos change when going on the `/videos` route the `log` command doesn't print anything anymore.

Also, I am using the `renderTemplate` function to get the functionality, something like that in the `VideosIndexRoute`:

```
this.render('videos.index', {
  outlet: 'videogrid',
  into: 'videos.index',
  controller: controller
});
```

And in the `ApplicationRoute` I have the same, just the `into` and the `controller` are for the `application` route.

So anyone knows how I can make ember rerender that template on the router-level? Or is there anything that I am missing and there is another/better way to do this? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Found a solution to it. I am now simply extending a pre-defined route that sets the isFrontpage and this.render accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a solution. The problem was, that ember loads the ApplicationRoute only one single time, so the renderTemplate method was never called again. I simply created a Route-object that all the other routes extend, so the right renderTemplate gets called for the right routes.